# How can you use asp.net core windows authentication alongside Cookie Authentication?

Tags: asp.net-core, active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc, windows-authentication, asp.net-core-middleware

I have an ASP.net Core (.net framework 4.7) application that is using cookie authentication like what is in [this link](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/05/13/cookie-authentication-asp-net-core/)

```
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
    {
        AuthenticationScheme = "CookieAuthentication",
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Login/"),
        AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Login/"),
        AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
        AutomaticChallenge = true
    });
```

What I want to do is allow windows authentication with Cookie authentication. So that if the user is in the company's domain he/she doesn't have to Enter user name and password.But if they are coming from an external domain they get redirected to the login page and enter their User name and password to be authenticated.

Comment: How do you currently authenticate the external domain users?

Comment: I do that through cookie authentication.

Answer (score 1):

> if the user is in the company's domain he/she doesn't have to Enter
>   user name and password.

`doesn't have to enter user name and password` is the tricky part. As far as I know, you cannot satisfy both authentication *at the same time*.

However, you can ask both type of users enter username and password, and authenticate with your system first. If authentication fails, you can authenticate with domain account.

If that scenario is workable, you can use [Novell.Directory.Ldap](https://github.com/dsbenghe/Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard) in ASP.NET Core. [Here](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit/blob/master/src/Libraries/Asp.NovellDirectoryLdap/LdapAuthenticationService.cs#L12) is the sample code.

```
public bool ValidateUser(string domainName, string username, string password)
{
   string userDn = $"{username}@{domainName}";
   try
   {
      using (var connection = new LdapConnection {SecureSocketLayer = false})
      {
         connection.Connect(domainName, LdapConnection.DEFAULT_PORT);
         connection.Bind(userDn, password);

         if (connection.Bound)
            return true;
      }
   }
   catch (LdapException ex)
   {
      // Log exception
   }
   return false;
}
```

*Note: As of today, System.DirectoryServices is not available in ASP.NET Core yet.*

Comment: I thought I can put the app.UseCookieAuthentication after app.UseMvc and enable windows auth and anonymous auth that way if windows auth didn't work the pipeline will continue to reach the CookieAuthentication. in the time allow my login controller to be accessed [AllowAnonymous] and the rest of the controller to have [Authorize] attribute. Is it possible in any way? 
Thank you,

Comment: You might be able to those two middle-ware together. I have never tried it, so I could not say for sure.